# web app randomly prompts for NTLM authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-6, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have an ASP.Net web application that I recently updated to framework 4.0. I had to install the new framework on the server that was running the app in production as well. The server is a 32 bit Windows 2003 Standard Edition running IIS 6. The application is using Windows authentication.

I say that the prompt is random as I have seen it in two different places under different circumstance.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Could you be linking to resources (e.g. image files, javascript files, etc.) that are requiring authentication.

Comment: they would be images and css files that are stored within the same folder as the web application.

Comment: I looked through the IIS logs and found that some of the requests were getting 401 errors. I have changed the permissions on the folder because it didn't match what was setup originally. I am waiting to hear back from my end user on the results.